# Export alv report to excel

Tags: excel, abap, alv

I have got a big problem with exporting ALV report to an Excel file.
I do not know if there are any standard functions of unloading ALV report to Excel.
I want implement this function as a special button.

Is it possible?

Comment: Assuming Your AVL is a typo of ALV, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly is Your problem ? If You did not exclude the "Export-button" from the ALV toolbar, You will have all stuff available via default:

[image]

And a short f4 search in se37 would also bring You interesting information:

[image]

You also cen debug the default ALV toolbar export-button in order to examine the internal routines.

Comment: TY. But now i have another problem. I dont know how to use function SALV_EXPORT_DATA_TO_APPL (parameters). e.g. s_param_lvc, export_type.

Comment: Then use "used where" helper and examine the other callers. And read the documentation.